# PHP Convert Byte Array to File Download

Tags: php, pdf, header, download

I receive a byte array from a third party source that is a PDF.  I need to convert that so a file is downloaded to the user.  I've implemented the code below and a download does occur but it's just a blank file.

If I echo the content of $fileToDownload, it is correct (starts with %PDF-, etc) and the data is there.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you in advance!

```
//GET CONTENT
$fileToDownload = $file->DownloadSignedDocumentResult;

//START DOWNLOAD
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fileToDownload));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($fileToDownload));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fileToDownload);
exit;
```

CONTENT OF echo $fileToDownload

(this file contains sensitive information so I'm only pasting a small snippet of the beginning of the file - hopefully that will be helpful):

%PDF-1.4 %���� 2 0 obj <> stream Dx��a/s�, ��v��"��Z�DƸ�1N�?ש�W� �d����A9���>�ˍ�u��Ҭ����F��;.��0ҷ�B;��s&ݩ%�]GP@Xb���I�䃶���8I�۪IJ����cR��!&�Q?ZG"��u7��Ζ�uY{^����[}���-�E�R.���� �r�u�����<���8b� ��a��9�Óㅅ�)1�Ĳ��/�� �zb����vD�VN�vD�|���ȓ�A�0��Ͻ�o*m���Z�gz�oH��\���V*;�\�Ӌ�=9��y��c������fT�O�����Kr"����Ԁ��������|��m'��% �!�@F ����|�A�j�)9�������g"���^m�Al�1���Bn�C9ύl�p�o{���]�k��x�5^y֡|щ���/�qقu���)�F��n`^ɞQ��6�Pc\e�۲]�8f� '�C[\v��U=���f��uIc�e�!�4^�ϻHCy��I��Gv(%�.I>��T�d!�l��׊R}�����B6k��=�C#���W.<���c��7���U���BI���! ����G�{�꾼L�2�q �I���Q�;;�P*�z�n��d尌(D�����aύ��7�����g�e���2����f�$��q�*�~+�H;R��t�Ofz����~|(�Jl��� l4�q�:�����w6.Z���ql݋�Њ+��hO��Ɔ�}<���pEs?�4З� h�07�����.���? ��s�F.�=�Z�Rz�9O�Hp��2��FR��nwH��{L`k�A�l{�f�u��g�p �@;���~���G>_n��P���ߪTJӗ�W��`��$pYJ<�Es�[�3J4=��/i��T)�(�����U�r�Jn��I��}��g��a�t�Ufw+�|�k�pu��� ���#Oy�J��y�\cOu���0[Y�������l~W|�'3-�.�0�AW�*�|��z�l�e��t8іDZ��Mh4dvS���*j���nHn���*��8w��~_��%�S��j7�xM�l�������t�YD@�� � K�(�!�*��P��[�U��(�@����z1S�����c�.9&�4����v�j�[}��F�%}���XS����X6�㕣�X��lV ��<�M>��C(ڼo��t;���i *ʸ-ua��a$�:��ȶ���}�Mz�׻���&H4���&�'[�o�l�C�|�ēM�c��'m$ ��)S�)+��� ̤�f>T0��x�] �w?w%���+˦�����,������]`F�����aڲ�:��b���3f�D@��Kg�kL��5V�Ei^c�G_I���H5)$�Ap,�����:���UӧR�J8~�����|�Ev�cUt=iJ)*��� �j��MOB\���m����c�~Q:~��1����Ev���z�H#�H��F+:G}掺 �f�d��f<��>�$�N�m�;��.s]�/S���?R�3�+���'�����Ң�1{*6=��g�-��v���|>��x*�V��m"�"��̔QC�.Al��:r?���|2�u������Ħё|?^���,u]48���֫���&T~2�x'5����᫏{�8ϋ��� ����WH���s��d2��1�n���?l�Ed�T���T'��Qm�"Y3ԾiZ�9����/G!$��Mj���)�m{m� ���`�R4_k7�c�a�����"m q~N2b�rí�%�῔��4�����0�+y���㳯̇O�!���.�F�\qZ0�fSZ� �Α�֩��"���ڐYNJ��{�{W���4ԝC�rg���/�-(C�<�O@��oS�,k�ǡ�*�PXz��o���%PfO0�@���l��t�oyw�a@(���A���!�OK��o��½q�8�Ǳ�Y�X���E�5���8ê��[5�Ƌ���M�)����t~��w��h�P��`�u?��    �w�kĵ��]"� �*gV�n�����B���4iw-�29�6}��Se����;v��m����F�[|ӥ�x���؋U��$>M���a��vij�܌   �� v����~]�ocf�<��L�䍞���J#(����nik�ث�R�u�"� N��1�}�y�T�S����r��+`�b�(9{7�����x��ux�ݚ}�6�    �C�=޻�����v�X�g���;9t�b_���l��am�ODQ��|���,�o禗�@�hkuݑ����t�d�ڐ��F�~*vh2��[���՞=$X� �pqH�_�7Ƒ�&�O�gǹ��I�]F}[%K�0�YN���Y�}����$���˱��i�~�Jk�*�c+{��Ђ���͉�v��u�9R����$�a�\;�N��쮴Tո���7�SMG|��Î�y�U�]]'Z�,MB��H�g@�&�rc��E0��i�����үmy���ONt��)(���)�I�D��;_� ŭ���N�Ks<(���!hE_�0"� ;U�{e2C�X�+��#|D���"�_#�]�Xu�6,Z��2���wNy�(0�z���4�;pn�<� zw`pD����1Clh�f���S!Q��C6��1G��'�P����"(�:��F� |aY�h�wL����o�G�tq�Q��,Hr�%(�Z�� ��J���>ŘŢz� u�j��#kг�z�cl��{�{�xRuJn���6��v�H7v �ocr�r����� ��L��%?���-&[r �ƢyF蒦O����v��a�������է����`��Y�Z�@��n?�i�f>Fh��B��w����}(�u�zm�~}�����!���&�n���]�- ��h9������na�bi�wS��q n#8��Y~��b=�441_����'c�ʠ=�b��wTj2�N*MO�$�}8["ƫg�6}�E�3�,�KE������_�e����dj�O3�n�7u]�<�m���_�`��a��.���+��&W�'�8�_�e����b���GI|   �\�92c�V�[�������*���Q�{(����a@Ğ�ك���Ѧ�j��Ut�S�� �۝�FM�F�0C�L`r`���uS�h��vI+��zC�n�$&��,@l�H����(naKf��f��� endstream endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj 7 0 obj <> endobj 8 0 obj <> endobj 9 0 obj <> endobj 10 0 obj /Creator <1408C602>/Keywords <>/ModDate <075D8656FF7B0721B23ACA5714F625E800F1D85A3259B0>/Producer <0E06D746811B1741A233CB4F1FE822FD7CB48D0F7613B7E5483D7D79CCF00F2321>/Title <0E0ED714A13B587FF622AC0E55A236F00D8289116D39F6CC2C2B7A5082C2052938040A6AC8D9>>> endobj 12 0 obj <> endobj 13 0 obj <> endobj 32 0 obj <> stream �_ `Q�"[�-�c��ozĖn¹#�b\���ו�Sn�i����cv��WS��WXi �hc4ŋ�ҳ� �3��/S(&�a�+����9�J����=�u�^N|4�]F��eBa]a� /M��uL���N����WK��dg�Z�^8gH��zEtqhB o<�ӣd�6�������_�B|������ ���XӑH^�q�7��ަ(���}���h�AN�`]���o�<�w���p=7��7*�[����������,�=?�{�-K|l֊��tiÞP��r鍪4[����p�b-��8բ� weZ1k��-{)i���=*l�K���~�<.�8_����h������+x> stream `�/�ă��3쫩0j|����KQ�����9D~�0ʛdP�*sa�^�!���j��b|μ���V�?�#�F �G��j� D��[��lE�@W+ȗ���+4��>$    "��������?< � _.�7K�j4���<6�+���+ �Y�h�G�'��=��C�������v�>V� ����Q��i�d���=��|@����m�99#{�߾Q2�^GL��X�w6�T(�'y����������K���Μ7U�*��+�NI1�0��z�#�Wn���i��̫���"��IS�ԅ4���|�\T��)/]��%m��b��A�u�V�p.�pD,z�߯u�O��k�.r}�ʚ�n��U�^�����"��ƙXv���WTd�戽v� � �^[~6ǈ�w%X��8��2���s��ڜؐ �vZ�7ga j�"O��v=���i8N^�r�����O>����M �������uC��0W��S�@^��������3���]:�t#Pj�ϳ��*�> stream r�V[tg�u�B�0��l���%�ቚ���XM�   ��.�0�Y�y�����Rt.�z[����Ή˨tnWUOH�B��'�"�޻�}SI��!Ǿ�7�~OVK�Cv�ѫ�y�� �����l�#y��$h�y�CJ�kq�rϴ��$mCg+�+������'�Сv��2���ԁ�N�����?<�V�58�%�.���ᕎЁ�(�u�i!Չ��fe��|���eq�<^9��ՙѩ'y�jϦ͏?g��D�Sb���rli� q�<��\�k`L[J����@�k��ܥ#��s�ͅ����p�!�ZO�I��{����A���уƒ��A�/t�al�"�����GW���>��+*��c���-�V�i�6IW�-\R�֨���l�4��f�~��'�к FuA�ԁ3��� ���;h^\˴L-���+�E�G(?s�y�� |�q�͟L�#]J    ��[p��|Z��q[��G��A ��;\�����3Y�c��vc�tk�K��a�t�rm(ˆ����F�ĝRנD*�6�efQ��3t��Wn���y*j~�P�vkt��6"� �������� ��1�a׆vX����?=���mv�7,��������/J+��E� �� /�N����UyMk�������k2���/����A��e���"C,��RG����Ӑ��J U�����JH�]Q���� endstream endobj 35 0 obj <>

Comment: can you do an echo of $fileToDownload and paste here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, $fileToDownload contains the binary data of the PDF, so you should just

```
echo $fileToDownload;
```

and also change:

```
header('Content-Length: '. strlen($fileToDownload));
```